# Why do I see a console window when I run a dynamically compiled EXE?

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a program that dynamically compiles a new program at the click of a button.

The new program generates and works perfectly.

The only weird thing is that when I run this newly generated exe, first a console window opens, the title is "C:\calculator.exe"

and then my calculator.exe program opens.

For some reason it is starting the console window and I'm not sure why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the code that is forking into the new exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the command line compiler? If so, try using `/target:winexe` instead of `/target:exe`.