# visual studio 2010 c# run-time compilation of winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, codedom, dynamic-compilation

I have the following problem, will try to describe it shortly.

In my program there is to be a possibility to compile a winform to an .exe by clicking on a button.

Now I tried to do it with CodeDom, so in my program I have the following line:

```
CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, text);
```

where **codeProvider** is CodeDomProvider and **text** is the source from where to compile.

Problem is the winform I need to save as an .exe has a class behind it that uses other classes and forms, and, since parameter 'text' is a string parameter, it has to include all those classes, which results in HUGE amount of code, not to mention plenty of mistakes. [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177446/how-do-i-hide-the-console-window-when-dynamically-compiling-a-windows-application)'s an example of what I mean.

There must be other ways, question is, what are they? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm sure we can find a better solution to your problem if you tell us what the business requirements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always use the same set of classes, it would be worth putting those common classes in a class library, and referring to that from the dynamically compiled code.

If they're *not* the same in every case, it's hard to see improvements you expect - if that much code has to be compiled, it has to be compiled, and there's that much code which can have mistakes in it.

Comment: The set of classes is the same, I'll try to follow your advice, thanks!

Comment: @Jon Skeet     Sorry to get back to the question, but I'm stuck again. I've created a class library and when I call it from my main project, creating an object, everything is fine.    But how do I pass it to the dynamically compiled code using CodeDom? How do I add it as the source from where to compile?     Bearing in mind that the constructor should take a parameter, so it looks like this:                                                               `CodeToCompile.TForm test = new CodeToCompile.TForm(TestElement.PanelsWithTestElements);`
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @tube-builder: Add a reference in the CompilerParameters you pass to CompileAssemblyFromSource. I'm not sure where the constructor comes into your question...

Comment: @Jon Skeet     I added the reference like this `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("CodeToCompile.dll");` Maybe I can't explain properly, I'm sorrty. I need to create an .exe(a winform) from my main project, and to this .exe I have to pass a list of Panel controls to populate this form. So I try to achieve it through CodeDom, unsuccessful so far.

Comment: @tube-builder: how would you expect to pass in controls, when you're starting a new process?

Comment: @Jon Skeet     It's just that it's the first time I come across using runtime compilation. How can I achieve what I need, then?

Comment: @tube-builder: One option is not to create a separate executable, but just a class library and call into that. You might want to look at what I've done for Snippy: http://csharpindepth.com/Files/snippy.zip

Comment: @Jon Skeet     Thank you, I will study your code and try to finally solve my problem. I really appreciate that you spend your time on this, thanks again.